# ListView - AnimatedContainers - only one expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Listview Builder which generates my list.
It returns AnimatedContainers.
The Animation triggers that my Container expands.

The problem is:
I want that only one AnimatedContainer is expanded at a time.
If one is already expanded and an other one gets selected, the previously selected one should shrink.

Is there way to achiev this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, someone is passing by:
I handled this by using BLoC.